# https.get() doesn't return UTF-8 characters

Tags: node.js, xml, https

I can't get the Turkish characters from the xml file. They seem to be question marks even when I set the encoding to utf-8.

```
https.get("https://clients1.google.com/complete/search?hl=tr&output=toolbar&q=mustafa kemal", (res) => {
            res.setEncoding("utf-8");
            var body = '';
            res.on('data', (d) => {
                body += d;
            })
            res.on('end', function(){
               console.log(body);
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the response content-type is not in `utf8` but `ISO-8859-9`

To check that do:

```
console.log(res.headers);

{
    date: 'Sat, 07 Jul 2018 17:02:46 GMT',
    expires: 'Sat, 07 Jul 2018 17:02:46 GMT',
    'cache-control': 'private, max-age=3600',
    'content-type': 'text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-9',
    p3p: 'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."',
    server: 'gws',
    'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
    'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN'
}
```

So if you do: `res.setEncoding('binary');` it will work just fine.

---

That request will return `utf8` instead of `ISO-8859-9` if you send `User-Agent` header.

```
const options = {
    hostname: 'clients1.google.com',
    path: '/complete/search?hl=tr&output=toolbar&q=mustafa+kemal',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
    }
};


https.get(options, (res) => {

    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    var body = '';

    res.on('data', (d) => {
        body += d;
    })

    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log(body);
    })
});
```

So in conclusion you should check the `Content-Type` header from the response, and set one encoding or the other.